# Display inline two p tag

Tags: html, css

I want to display two p tags in same line, one left and one right as below :

```
<p >This is a paragraph.</p>
<p style="text-align : right">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

In the CSS, I am doing below :

```css
p {display: inline-block;}
```

But this is not giving me the desired output. Instead its showing both the sentences together like below :

> This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use float:left on the first p and float:right on the second.

HTML

```
<div>
   <p class="pull-left">Text in left paragraph</p>
   <p class="pull-right">Text in right paragraph</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.pull-left {float:left;}
.pull-right {float:right;}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x89a6/)

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to do that? `<p>` stands for "paragraph". If you want two of these in the same line, you should use another tag, such as `<span>`.